# Extract number between specific symbols in Excel

Tags: excel, extract

I will need help how to extract the number inside this string:

test-343-image(1)(Pic2).jpg

I will need the second number after `"(Pic"` and before `").jpg"`  which is 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would the string where you pull numbers from always follow this same pattern? In other words....is the number to be pulled always between `(Pic` and `).jpg`?

Comment: The pattern before "(Pic" can be different kind of numbers, letters or symbols, but always is the same pattern between "(Pic" and ").jpg" and always there is a number. The number is between 1 and 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably multiple ways, for example:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("(Pic",A1)+4,99),").jpg","")
```

And if your number can only between 1-9 then the following would be enough:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(Pic",A1)+4,1)
```

Or:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6),1)
```

Comment: At the same time I found one more solution, with fixed size, because I know always it's the 6 character in the row from the right side if you start counting.
`=LEFT(RIGHT(B1;FIND("(Pic";B1)-6);1)` 


But can you explain only what is the meaning of "4,99"?

Comment: That is only usefull if the number isn't a fixed size. 4 is the number of characters used for `(Pic`, then 99 is just a way to be safe to extract the rest of the string. Best is to use `Evaluate` if you are unsure what it does. @mnves